# Create link to new controller dokumente

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ive created an new controller:

```
rails g controller dokumente index
```

Added to my routes:

```
get "dokumente/index"
```

And now i tried to link to this site but always get an route error! So how do i have to make the link? Thanks!

```
 <li><a href="...">Dokumente</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
<%= link_to 'Dokumente', controller: 'dokumente', action: 'index' %>
```